# Casting type in polymer Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a problem and I can`t solve it.
I have 2 polymer element nested.

In principal HTML page: **index.html**

```html
<poly-container a="Hi">
    <poly-item b="hi"></poly-item>
</poly-container>
```

In Polymer HTML definition: **polycontainer.html**

```html
<poly-container>
    <template> ...
    <content></content>
</poly-container>
```

In Dart class: **polycontainer.dart**
...Have tag `<content>` for render external DOM;
...and the 2 classes: `PolyContainer` and `PolyItem`

```dart
...  
ContentElement CE=shadowRoot.querySelectAll('content');
List<Node> LN= CE.getDistributedNodes();

//  LN[i] is a Node type, but we know is an element with type PolyItem.

for (var i=0; i < ......) {
    PolyItem PI= ( cast ) LN[i];    // Error in time running only;
     ......
}
```

...I tried several ways.
I can't access to  element `PolyItem`.  Only access to Node. I can't cast.

How do it ???

Comment: If you think you got a good answer you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark below the vote count.

Answer (score 2):

```dart
PolyItem pi = (ln[i] as PolyItem);
```

returns a `PolyItem` if it is one or throws an exception if it isn't.

to avoid the exception you can check previously

```dart
PolyItem pi;
if(ln[i] is PolyItem) {
  pi = ln[i];
}
...
```

Please don't use uppercase names for variables:

PI => pi
LN => ln

Its uncommon, ugly and against the Dart style guide.
Uppercase is usually used for constants and helps distinguish intention if used consistently.
You have much better chance to get a good answer if you format your question and code well.

Comment: Thanks Günter.Dart keep style in my code. But not right they saw the letters in the editor, so I put in all caps. I'll get it for the next.
Thank you again.

Comment: No prob, just a little support to help you beeing a good citizen and have more fun ;-)